# ASP.NET: does it involve Active X at all?

Tags: asp.net, security, user-interface, activex

Sorry, really newbie question, but if I was to create an ASP.NET website application, such as a calendar of events linked to a database - would the user interacting with this Calendar be using Active X?

Don't really know how to put that question any other way. Reason I ask is that my works system blocks Active X controls and therefore there would be no point in using ASP.NET to develop anything.

As a side question - What doesn't use Active X?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ASP.NET doesn't use ActiveX unless you make it do so, via interop.

There are many ASP.NET controls etc that will do what you want and use JavaScript etc rather than ActiveX.  For really slick dynamic stuff MS are pushing [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/), which is their competitor to Flash in many ways.

Answer (score 6):

ASP.NET is a server side technology and does not necessarily have anything to do with client side technologies such as ActiveX or anything else.